# Running GCC and binutils on JVM

Tags: gcc, jvm, cross-compiling, binutils

I was wondering whether the is a way to run GCC compiler suite and binutils on top of JVM so that the compiler would generate x86/ARM/MIPS binary as its output. This would be like crosscompiling, but the host system would be JVM instead of the native host system. The target of the compiler would be x86/ARM/MIPS/whatever GCC supports.

This would be beneficial for at least embedded programmers that need to use crosscompilers for the target system. Currently the GCC needs to be built for the host system, and the built again for the target instruction set (ISA). If the GCC would run on JVM, the compiler could be run unmodified whether it is being run on Linux, Windows, BSD, Unix or whatever system that supports JVM.

This might also help porting the GCC compiler suite for various host systems, as is needs only support JVM as a running environment.

Any comments or ideas?

Comment: Well, GCC already is ported to, like, a _bazillion_ different platforms, so finding a host platform that doesn't support GCC is actually quite hard. It probably runs on more platforms than any JVM.

Comment: Unless you find a C/C++ to Java bytecode compiler, you'll be out of luck.

Comment: I will answer to myself. It seems that the GCC cannot target directly to JVM, but there is NestedVM http://nestedvm.ibex.org/ which essentially converts MIPS binary to JVM. Basically this might be the way how to do it: at first take GCC cross-compiler and toolchain with MIPS target and convert it with NestedVM to JVM. Now we have a GCC-to-MIPS tool chain running on JVM. Next we need to bootstrap the MIPS GCC compiler to produce target architecture binaries. This is a bit complicated, but it may be doable.

Comment: I also found an old post dated back to 2001 "java bytecode considered bad": http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-02/msg00895.html